# How to use AsyncPostBackTrigger to trigger functions from the backend to show progress bar on the front-end?

Tags: javascript, sql-server, vb.net, asynchronous

I'm using UpdatePanel to fill a progress bar whenever a function on the backend is executed. The user first has to upload a csv file. Once the csv file is uploaded and saved temporarily, the user then presses another button (let's call it "update and view") that runs a series of functions to clean the csv file and convert it to a json file. Some csv files are large and it's hard to tell which function the csv is running through when executed.

However, the problem is every time the user presses the "update and view" button, nothing happens. I receive an error from the console that the object reference is not set to an instance of an object.

Since my button is outside of the UpdatePanel, I made sure to have  set within the UpdatePanel. I made sure the EventName="click". For UpdatePanel, I made sure my UpdateMode="Conditional" since I only want the progress bar to fill whenever a function has completed running. I set my ChildrenAsTriggers="true" - it didn't matter if I changed this setting to "false". The button still did not execute the functions I made. In addition, I made sure in my aspx page that Async="true". I use asp:AsyncPostBackTriggers and not asp:PostBackTriggers. I wonder if this was the issue, but I don't believe it is because I'm trying to run the backend the same time while updating my front end progress bar. Below, is sample code from the backend (vb) and sample code from the front end.

```
 Protected Sub BtnUpload_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

    statusLabel.Text = ""

    While statusLabel.Text = ""
        statusLabel.Text = Test_CSV()
        Try
            loadbar.Style("width") = "10%"
            updateP.Update()
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.ToString)
        End Try
        statusLabel.Text = Save_CSV()

        statusLabel.Text = Create_tables("fileOne")


        statusLabel.Text = Transfer_Tables("fileOne")


        statusLabel.Text = Update_Tables("fileOne")

        statusLabel.Text = Query_JSON()



    End While

    FileUploadControl.Enabled = False
    BtnUpload.Enabled = False
    FileUploadControl.Visible = False
    BtnUpload.Visible = False


    Response.Redirect("/summary/filesummary.aspx")


End Sub
```

```
  <div class="row" style="padding-left: 0; padding-top: .5em;">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <label class="file-upload">
            <span id="selectcsv" runat="server">Select CSV File                   
                 <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUploadControl" runat="server"                        
       onchange="document.getElementById('uploadText').style.display =            
    'block';showFile();document.getElementById('instruction').style.display = 
   'none';" CssClass="hidden" /></span>
        </label>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row" style="margin-bottom: 1em;">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <label class="file-upload" id="uploadText" style="display: none;">
            <span>Update and view results</span>
            <asp:Button runat="server" ID="BtnUpload" OnClick="BtnUpload_Click" CssClass="hidden"/>
        </label>
        <asp:Label CssClass="label" runat="server" ID="statusLabel"></asp:Label>
    </div>
</div>


    <asp:UpdatePanel id="updateP" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional" 
               ChildrenAsTriggers="false">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <div role="progressbar" class="progress-bar" id="loadbar" 
            style="width: 0%" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" 
             runat="server"></div>
        </ContentTemplate>
        <Triggers>
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="BtnUpload" 
             EventName="click" runat="server"/>
        </Triggers>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

I put a try/catch statement to see if I could get a more detailed error box, but nothing appeared. I at least expected my progress bar to fill 10% (it's based on the style attribute of width. I didn't show any of css class in detail, but the bar will color in when you change the width is the idea). But, again nothing happened I had the error where

> object reference is not set to an instance of an object.

The error occurs at line 1 of MAjax. I wasn't sure what this meant.

Comment: where is the code `MAjax`

Comment: it's the error that shows up when you inspect the page. Here is it exactly: Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
    at Function.Error.create (MsAjaxJs?v=D6VN0fHlwFSIWjbVzi6mZyE9Ls-4LNrSSYVGRU46XF81:1)

Answer (score 0):

1. I don't see any FileUploadControl in your design file.
2. updateP.Update do not send a changed html on your frontend immediately. It will be send it on the end of Page processing only. You need use a timer who will send async request on a server and get current status of uploading. I run upload file at the separated thread. Due to it timer enabled and started on server without additional client code. And i have used runtime cache for a work status storing.

```
<div class="row" style="margin-bottom: 1em;">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <label class="file-upload" id="uploadText">
                <span>Update and view results</span>
                <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnConvert" OnClick="btnConvert_Click" CssClass="hidden" />
            </label>
            <asp:Label CssClass="label" runat="server" ID="statusLabel"></asp:Label>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row" style="margin-bottom: 1em;">
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <asp:FileUpload ID="fileUpload1" runat="server" />            
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-9">
            <asp:Button ID="btnUploadFile" Text="Upload file" runat="server" OnClick="btnUploadFile_Click" />
        </div>
    </div>

    <asp:Timer ID="timerGetStatus" runat="server" Interval="1000" OnTick="timerGetStatus_Tick" Enabled="false"></asp:Timer>

    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="updateP" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional" ChildrenAsTriggers="false">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="progress">
                    <div id="loadbar" runat="server" class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="0" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </ContentTemplate>
        <Triggers>
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="timerGetStatus" EventName="Tick" runat="server" />
        </Triggers>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

```
Imports System.Threading
Imports System.Threading.Tasks

Public Class _Default
    Inherits Page

    Public Property FileId As Guid?
        Get
            Return CType(ViewState("FileId"), Guid?)
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Guid?)
            ViewState("FileId") = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    End Sub

    Protected Sub btnConvert_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
        Task.Run(
            Sub()
                ConvertFile(FileId.Value)
            End Sub)
        timerGetStatus.Enabled = True
    End Sub

    Private Sub ConvertFile(ByVal workId As Guid)
        Save_CSV()
        Create_tables()
        Transfer_Tables()
        Update_Tables()
        Query_JSON()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Save_CSV()
        Dim text As String = GetFile()
        Thread.Sleep(1000)
        ChangeProgress(20)
    End Sub

    Private Sub Create_tables()
        Dim text As String = GetFile()
        Thread.Sleep(3000)
        ChangeProgress(30)
    End Sub

    Private Sub Transfer_Tables()
        Dim text As String = GetFile()
        Thread.Sleep(2000)
        ChangeProgress(50)
    End Sub

    Private Sub Update_Tables()
        Dim text As String = GetFile()
        Thread.Sleep(6000)
        ChangeProgress(80)
    End Sub

    Private Sub Query_JSON()
        Dim text As String = GetFile()
        Thread.Sleep(4000)
        ChangeProgress(100)
    End Sub

    Protected Sub timerGetStatus_Tick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
        ShowProgress()
        If GetProgress() = 100 Then
            timerGetStatus.Enabled = False
        End If
    End Sub

    Protected Sub btnUploadFile_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
        FileId = Guid.NewGuid()
        Cache($"File_{FileId}") = fileUpload1.FileBytes
        ChangeProgress(10)
        ShowProgress()
    End Sub

    Private Function GetFile() As String
        Return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Cache($"File_{FileId}"))
    End Function

    Private Sub ChangeProgress(progress As Integer)
        Cache($"Progress_{FileId.Value}") = progress
    End Sub

    Private Function GetProgress() As Integer
        Return Cache($"Progress_{FileId.Value}")
    End Function

    Private Sub ShowProgress()
        If FileId.HasValue Then
            loadbar.Style.Add("Width", $"{GetProgress()}%")
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Now that makes sense with Update(). Yes, I didn't show the front end with the FileUploadControl but it is there in my full code. I will edit the code in this question to reflect it. I'll try out the code you wrote out and and let you know if it helped resolve the issue.

Comment: The timer is a good idea, but I'm not trying to time how long it takes to upload a file. I'm trying to show how long it takes for a file to be converted with the functions shown in my original question. The user first uploads a file. That's the quick part. But then, the user has to press another button that will run the uploaded file through 6 different functions when you click "BtnUpload" (sorry not the best naming convention). What exactly would I be running through Task.Run? Let me know if you need me to clarify! Thank you!

Comment: @Aileen Timer is a good idea yet. I updated the example by light the way: added conversion stages to illustrate a prime idea how to inform an user about changes during a process of file.

Comment: Thank you Vasil! I will try this again.

Comment: @Aileen i glad to help